# value not rendering in textarea using patchValue

Tags: angular, typescript

**I am trying to render the dynamic values to textarea  while the selectbox change. but i am not able to render in textarea but values change in form.value.** 
I tried to assign value to textarea dynamically when changing the selectbox, But textarea value not changing. Form values are changing when i am checking with {{myForm.value | json}}. Below is my source code to update the value in textarea using patch value in app.component.ts file. `this.myForm.value.users[0].patchValue({street: 'mtmmm'});`

I tried but not working any body help while selecting select box particular array object i am getting gut try to assign street to textarea it's not working .
Below is my source code URL
[CODE URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup2-selectbox-qpzhgs?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Below is my form builder code:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
users: this.fb.array([])
})
let dataArr = new FormArray([]);
dataArr.push(new FormGroup({
'company': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].company),
'address': new FormControl(this.users[0].data[0].address)
}));
let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
formArr.push(fb.group({
firstname: this.users[0].firstname,
lastname: this.users[0].lastname,
street: this.users[0].street,
data: dataArr
}));
}
```

and below is the selectbox change event, i have filter data based on selected value, after getting array object i try to assign textareat, but it's not rendering.

```js
selectarch(cat){
this.test=this.users.filter(data =>data.firstname === cat.target.value);

this.myForm.value.users[0].street=this.test[0].street;
this.myForm.value.users[0].firstname=this.test[0].firstname;
this.myForm.value.users[0].lastname=this.test[0].lastname;

var test = this.myForm.get('users[0].street');
test.setValue('mtmmm');

}
```

Comment: can you post how you've implemented the forms ? are you using formBuilder ?

Comment: Yes, i have attached the code, its not render date while selectbox change event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `controls` instead of `value`, so something like this:

```
// to avoid error of controls doesn't exist on abstractcontrol:
let arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
arr.controls[0].patchValue({...})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var test = this.myForm.get('users[0].street');
test.setValue('mtmmm');
```